# Change Umbraco CMS theme / style (Free)

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, umbraco

Does anyone know how I can change Umbraco CMS theme. 
(not for the website front-end, but just for the CMS front-end)

- Are there any free templates available for download?
- Are there any easy ways of styling it myself without digging to deep into Umbraco's code?

I want to make the GUI more user-friendly for non-admin users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Belle was announced in 2012 at the Umbraco UK Festival and again in the [November 2012 issue](http://umbraco.cmail5.com/t/ViewEmail/y/D2843F6FAE874C2C/60219303DA496B196E6039C17E42EE19#toc_item_0) of uNews. Here are some points on it:

- It's due to be released in the spring/summer of 2013.
- It is a full refresh of the Umbraco back office user interface and in my opinion it looks great.
- It is currently a separate open source project and is available on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/UmbracoHQ/umbracocms-belleui).
- Bluegrass Digital has a good [blog post](http://www.bluegrassdigital.com/blog/2012/november/6/umbraco-uk-festival-meet-project-belle/) that highlights its main features.
- Brenden Rice has a [working demo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/umbraco-ux/L2MBPNMfatA/dLGazBTDq0AJ) of Belle available for anyone who wants to check it out.

Instead of attempting to re-style the Umbraco back office yourself, I would recommend contributing to the project. You could even use a pre-release version of Belle if you don't want to wait. Unfortunately there are no other "themes" available.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, yes the Belle "theme" looks a million times better than the existing one. I will try to make time to contribute. Cheers buddy